# transfer data from view to controller and back to view

Tags: yii

been days im struggling with this.  the problem is as follows...

I'm a newbie in the world of yii

So i have got a page 'resultat' and on selecting different menus, the content needs to be change through ajax.

Here the view:

```
 <!--Content_Resultat-->
<div class="content_resultat">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header_top">
            <div class="centerheader"> 
            <a href="#">retournez à l'étape en cours</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header_bottom">
        <ul class="centerlist">
            <li><a href="#"><span>1</span> votre piece</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>2</span> votre exigence</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>3</span> vos autre apareils</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>4</span> votre utilisation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="barre_titre">
        <a href="#">
            pour vous, lg vous propose
        </a>
        <div class="print">
            <a href="#">imprimer la liste</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm();?>
        <div class="onglet">
            <ul class="menu"> 
                 <?php $i = 1;
                    foreach ($data as $categorie) {?>
                    <li class="active">
                     <div class="onglet<?php echo $i;?>">
                        <img alt="no-picture" src="<?php echo $categorie->image;?>" />
                        <h4><?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
                        $categorie->titre,
                            Yii::app()->createUrl('getproduit'),
                            array('type'=>'POST',
                                'dataType' =>'json',
                                'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
                                'update'=>'#carousel_container .contentWrapper #carousel_inner',
                                'data'=>'js:jQuery(".menu li h4 a").serialize()',
                                'success'=>'function(data){ $("#carousel_container li").text(data);}',

                                'error'=>'function(a,b,c){alert(b)}'
                  ));?></h4>
                     </div>
                    </li>   

                <?php $i++; }?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel_tv" id="carousel_container">

            <div class="contentWrapper">
                <div id="carousel_inner">
                    <ul id="carousel_ul">
                        <li>
                            <div class="carousel_pic">
                                <img alt="no-picture" src="images/image1.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <h3>gamme le5510</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius nulla eu neque porttitor in mattis lectus pulvinar. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="carousel_pic">
                                <img alt="no-picture" src="images/image2.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <h3>gamme le5510</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius nulla eu neque porttitor in mattis lectus pulvinar. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="carousel_pic">
                                <img alt="no-picture" src="images/image3.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <h3>gamme le5510</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius nulla eu neque porttitor in mattis lectus pulvinar. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="carousel_pic">
                                <img alt="no-picture" src="images/image1.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <h3>gamme le5510</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius nulla eu neque porttitor in mattis lectus pulvinar. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="carousel_pic">
                                <img alt="no-picture" src="images/image2.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <h3>gamme le5510</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius nulla eu neque porttitor in mattis lectus pulvinar. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="carousel_pic">
                                <img alt="no-picture" src="images/image3.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <h3>gamme le5510</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius nulla eu neque porttitor in mattis lectus pulvinar. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="carousel_pic">
                                <img alt="no-picture" src="images/image1.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <h3>gamme le5510</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius nulla eu neque porttitor in mattis lectus pulvinar. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="carousel_pic">
                                <img alt="no-picture" src="images/image2.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <h3>gamme le5510</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius nulla eu neque porttitor in mattis lectus pulvinar. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="carousel_pic">
                                <img alt="no-picture" src="images/image3.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <h3>gamme le5510</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius nulla eu neque porttitor in mattis lectus pulvinar. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>No Content</h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>No Content</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm();?>
```

the data is being displayed through an xml.

the controller:

```
    public function actionGetproduit(){
    $obj_produit = new Gamme();
    $produits = $obj_produit->get_produits('tv');

    foreach ($produits as $data){

        echo CHtml::tag('produit',array('style'=>'display:block'),CHtml::encode($data),true);


    }
```

}

I need the data being send from the controller to be displayed on the view..

But unable to do it, any help plss

Thanks :-(

Answer (score 0):

For ajax returns, you generally would can use [renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail) or echo the results as you have it, but the CHtml::tag functions you would usually pass an HTML object for the tag name, see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#tag-detail) or [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#openTag-detail) but it looks like your function is expecting JSON, so you would need to output your results as JSON, see the [Yii JSON methods](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON). If that's not the issue, you might need to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Normally with Yii on ajax button or link or what ever the case might be, you do a on success

```
array('success'=>'js:function(data) {
 jQuery("div#status").html(data);
}
```

and inside your controller, you can echo the response back to your view. Also make sure you have jQuery loaded in the view!